# How do I position imported Slack data into specific cells on Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api

I am using a small script that sends data from slack to google sheets using slash command.. I have been playing all day but just cant figure out how to get each piece of data in the column I choose. The data string I have is 
`var slackDetails = [date,teamDomain,bookName,userName,channelName];`

Where date = A1, teamDomain = B1, bookName = C1, userName = D1, channelName = E1
And then when a new entry is made, it drops down to row 2.

I am trying to find out if it is possible to be able to set which columns the data goes into? example date = A1, teamDomain = E1, bookName = F1 etc.

so I can choose which columns I want the data to appear.

Everything haha. I have searched high and low but cannot seem to find anything that works. I am pretty new to Google Apps scrips so have been on a Google hunt most of the day

Complete code to the script is

````
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));

    // extract the relevant data
    var parameter = e.parameter;
    var teamDomain = parameter.team_domain;
    var channelName = parameter.channel_name;
    var userName = parameter.user_name;
    var bookName = parameter.text;
    var date = new Date();
    var slackDetails = [date,teamDomain,bookName,userName,channelName];

    // paste the slack details to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,5).setValues([slackDetails]);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(':nerd_face: Your entry has been added to the report! :h-check:');```

I expect the output to be in a specific order and specific columns
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the elements of the *slackdetails* array is the order in which data will be put into columns.

So if you want date = A1, then columns B, C and D to be blank and then teamDomain = E1, bookName = F1 etc. try this:

```
var slackDetails = [date, "", "", "", teamDomain,bookName,userName,channelName];

// paste the slack details to the sheet
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,slackDetails.length).setValues([slackDetails]);
```